# Error: Simba Hive ODBC connector requires Visual C++ 2010 runtimes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, visual-c++, redistributable

I'm trying to install Simba ODBC connector on Windows Server 2008 x64. After clicking on installation file, I get an error:

```
Simba ODBC connector requires Visual C++ 2010 runtimes (64 bit).
Please use Windows update to install this and then re-run the setup program.
```

I went to control Panel --> Programs and Features , and I found there Microsoft Visual C++      2010 Redistributable installed.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 2010 requires  Windows Server 2008 R2 (and I had Windows Server 2008 )
Then I:

1. Switched to  Windows Server 2008 R2
2. Installed Visual C++ 2010 from Microsoft official page
3. Then installed Simba ODBC connector!